# Как отправить сообщение в канал с помощью бота telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Вот делаю запрос

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot187976149:AAGgl9VtPkDxh*********/sendMessage?chat_id=@test&text="hellow!"
```

@test -- имя моего канала

---

В ответ приходит ----> 
Bad Request: channel not found"
Что я не так делаю? Почему не может найти канал?

Comment: напишите, на каком языке создаете бота, и где вы используете этот *странный* запрос

Comment: @approximatenumber Уже разобрался, неправильный идентификатор поставил, нужно использовать идентификатор с ссылки на канал, от как раз уникальный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, неправильный идентификатор поставил, нужно использовать идентификатор с ссылки на канал, он как раз уникальный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot187976149:AAGgl9VtPkDxh*********/sendMessage?chat_id=@test345674&text="hellow!"
```